# how JNDI lookup finds a java class?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, rmi

I have an EJB bean with remote interface. It's included in war file chapter08-service-1.0.

```
@Remote
public interface BookEJBRemote {
    ...
}
```

After I deploy it on glassfish I can call it from a client using

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
BookEJBRemote bookEJB = (BookEJBRemote) ctx.lookup("java:global/chapter08-service-1.0/BookEJB!org.agoncal.book.javaee7.chapter08.BookEJBRemote");
```

It works fine and calls the method. But I don't understand how is it finding the EJB or even glassfish instance? Obviously there is no clue about server or port of the glassfish in the lookup string.

Comment: It doesn't 'find a Java class'. It finds a Java *object,* by name, in a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't understand how is it finding the EJB or even glassfish
>   instance.instance.

In order to get an EJB reference through a JNDI service, basically you need to:

1. connect to the JNDI server
2. once connected, to lookup an object using the name which it was
   registered with.

To connect to the JNDI server, you need to provide to InitialContext object several information such ip/port where JNDI server is listening. There are different ways to initialize the initialContext as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937514/how-do-i-specify-a-server-to-get-an-ejb-from/18945693#18945693).

If you don't provide this information the InitialContext will try to search the service in  localhost with default port as suggested in the previous answer.

> Obviously there is no clue about server or port of the glassfish in
>   the lookup string.

Due to the described above, you will not see url or port information as part of lookup name parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running glassfish and your client in the same computer, it can be that they are both using the default JNDI port 1099, and since both are on the same computer, there's no need to specify a host.

So the way it works, is that your client first contacts the JNDI server and the JNDI server returns where is that the EJB is located (usually which host and port where the EJB is available).

I don't want to sound negative, but EJBs proved to be a technology that didn't deliver what it promised and most companies have long time ago ditched EJBs or are trying hard to get away from them.

Comment: Good Answer to the question, but avoid the rant

Answer (score 0):

InitialContext **does not** just pick a default host (localhost) and a default port number. This information is explicitely set by glassfish itself, which is done using the Java Webstart technology.

You can test it by yourself: Assuming your application client is deployed to the context `localhost:8080/YourClient`. When you visit the link, a JNLP file is being downloaded and started by Webstart. You can manually save the file instead of letting it be opened automatically (that would be `wget localhost:8080/YourClient` on Linux, for instance). You'll see that Glassfish initializes your client application with a lot of parameters, including the JNDI-related properties:

```
<property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory"/>
<property name="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs" value="com.sun.enterprise.naming"/>
<property name="java.naming.factory.state" value="com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl"/>
<property name="appclient.iiop.defaultHost" value="localhost"/>
<property name="appclient.iiop.defaultPort" value="${request.appclient.iiop.defaultPort}"/>
<property name="${appclient.download.host.propertyName}" value="localhost"/>
<property name="${appclient.user.code.is.signed.propertyName}" value="${appclient.user.code.is.signed}"/>
```

These properties are not just specified for your convenience, they are mandatory. Try to start your client application as a stand-alone application (just run the main class in your favorite IDE): in such a situation, the initial parameters won't be set. You'll notice that InitialContext doesn't work so well without these properties.

**Short answer to your question**: InitialContext finds Glassfish and the EJB's, because your application was started with special parameters telling InitialContext where to look, how to initialize required classes, etc.